# CSG library doing volume difference?

Tags: graphics, 3d

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constructive_solid_geometry

I'm much interested in doing what the first pictures describe on this article, only that I'm only interested in doing it on parallelepipeds (cube-like shapes), so no sphere or tube or circular shapes whatsoever.

There is this library, http://www.cgal.org/ , but it has a lot of features, and I don't know if it does what I'm looking for, and if yes, what parts could I use ?

Do you know any other library that does what I want ?

C/C++ is preferred over C#/java, but I'm open... The goal being to not reinvent the wheel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need only rendering (no mesh generation), look at [this](http://www.opencsg.org/).

If you need to generate new mesh:

- [UnBBoolean/J3DBool](http://unbboolean.sourceforge.net/) (Java)
- [J3DBool ported to C++](http://code.google.com/p/createuniverses/downloads/detail?name=CSGTestWorld_src.zip&can=2&q=), [modified for QT](http://code.google.com/p/createuniverses/downloads/detail?name=QtCSG_src.zip&can=2&q=), [modified for Ogre](http://code.google.com/p/ogrecsglib/)
- [Carve](http://code.google.com/p/carve/) (C++) (it is used in Blender, but I was unable to make it work + obsolete documentation)
- [GTS Library](http://gts.sourceforge.net/) (C++) (maybe too overkill)

Personaly, I picked [Ogre version](http://code.google.com/p/ogrecsglib/), rewrote to use STL containers (it use fixed size for face count) and slightly optimized.

Comment: opencsg seems a little too scientific-oriented, and quite too complex to use (the api seems to be written in a c fashion, unusable imo), but I was not aware about the ogre version, I'm quite surprised to see there is one. I'm interested in doing procedural models and I'm using ogre, so it's perfect, thanks a lot !

Answer (score 1):

A list of libraries can be found [here](https://github.com/openscad/openscad/wiki/Project%3A-Survey-of-CSG-algorithms)